# Помогатор написания кода в VS22

Tags: c#, visual-studio

При написании кода в `VS22` есть какой то помогатор. Который предугадывает строку кода серым цветом и на `tab` её можно записать.

Иногда в тему, но чаще нет.
Иногда даже сниппет `for` например мешает реализовать.

Как этого помогатора отключить или настроить ?
Что это за зверь ?

Comment: Зовется IntelliSense и IntelliCode, где второй например обучается на основе вашего кода (в поиске IntelliCode пишем и там найдете обучение его).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну вот да,`IntelliCode` мешает очень) спасибо!